# How do I specify the build machine size for CloudBees builds

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

If I want to set the jenkins build slave machine size - eg to restrict it to "m1.large" size - how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the option "restrict where this build can run" and place in it "m1.large"

see here http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/m1.large+support+for+Jenkins+jobs